# Matplotlib distance between subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have 3x3 `matplotlib` axes containing `sns.heatmap`. To the left of and upwards from the main heatmap `ax[1][1]` (that is 2D rectangle, say shape is 10x25 ) two additional heatmaps are placed (say 10x1 and 1x25).

The distance between the main heatmap and the two other depends on the shape[0] and shape[1] proportion of the content of the main heatmap...

I haven't found a way to keep it constant, so if I try to plot an array that has larger disproportion in dimensions (say 50 x 10) one of the distances gets ridiculously high :(

This https://ibb.co/rx9DRgp image shows unequal x and y distances produced by the following code, that demonstrates the issue....

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

YZ = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=(10,25))
XB = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=(25,1))
XA = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=(10,1))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(
    3,3,
    figsize=( YZ.shape[1], YZ.shape[0], ),
    gridspec_kw={
        "width_ratios"  : [ 1, YZ.shape[1], 0.5 ],
        "height_ratios" : [ 1, YZ.shape[0], 0.5 ],
    }
)

with sns.axes_style("darkgrid"):
    hm = {}; hm[0],hm[1],hm[2] = {},{},{}
    hm[1][1] = sns.heatmap(
        data       = YZ,
        ax         = ax[1][1],
        square     = True,
        annot_kws  = {"size": 8},
        linewidths = 0,
        cbar       = True,
        cbar_ax    = ax[1][2],
    )
    hm[1][0] = sns.heatmap(
        data       = XA,
        ax         = ax[1][0],
        square     = True,
        annot_kws  = {"size": 8},
        linewidths = 2,
        linecolor  = "white",
        cbar       = False,
    )
    hm[0][1] = sns.heatmap(
        data       = XB.T,
        ax         = ax[0][1],
        square     = True,
        annot_kws  = {"size": 8},
        linewidths = 2,
        linecolor  = "white",
        cbar       = False,
    )
ax[1][1].get_shared_x_axes().join( ax[1][1], ax[0][1] )
ax[1][1].get_shared_y_axes().join( ax[1][1], ax[1][0] )
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Is there a simple way to keep the distance between the axes constant (say 10% of the image width or 200px) for both discances

I have no idea how to make the distance between `ax[1][1]` and `ax[1][0]` to be the same as distance between `ax[1][1]` and `ax[0][1]`...

Comment: The problem is that, while the width-to-height ratio of your subplot changes, the width-to-height ratio of your figure does not. Now matplotlib always tries to fill the available space as well as possible, which is why you get these different distances between the subplots. Instead of a gridspec, you could use an AxesDivider as is explained in [this tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html#scatter-hist-py-with-axesdivider) -- with the right `pad` the distances between the axes should stay the same.

Comment: As @ThomasKühn says, matplotlib assigns subplot slots with no assumption about the aspect ratio of the axes in thee subplot.  But various `imshow` methods set the aspect ratio, and matplotlib just makes that fit inside the larger subplot slot, with messy gaps the result.  I think the canonical tutorial is https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/toolkits/axes_grid.html#axes-grid1-users-guide-index